# React Native Animatable: Conditional Animated View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using [React Native Animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable). I have the following `Animatable.View`:

```
<Animatable.View ref={ref => this.view = ref} animation="fadeInUp">
   <TextInput style={{ flex: 1 }}
     value={this.state.text}
     onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ text: text }) }}
   />
</Animatable.View>
```

When I press a button I trigger the `Animatable.View`, using its reference (`this.view`), to perform either:

- an **in animation** (`this.view.fadeInUp(300);`)
- or an **out animation**(`this.view.fadeOutDown(300);`)

However, I wish to have the `Animatable.View` initially hidden. I want it to render and appear using the animation only after the button is pressed. How is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a state and set that to true when button is triggered first time

```
{this.state. show && Animatable.View ref={ref => this.view = ref} animation="fadeInUp">
   <TextInput style={{ flex: 1 }}
     value={this.state.text}
     onChangeText={(text) => { this.setState({ text: text }) }}
   />
</Animatable.View>}
```

Comment: `none` caused an error and it did not work. I also tried `undefined` which successfully did not perform the animation, however the element is still visible. I wish it to be hidden until triggered by the button and fadeIn animation.

Comment: Another option is to hide the Animatable.View section with a state varaiable